# Conditional value base on build status in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

So I have this `pipeline`:

```
pipeline {

    agent {
        node {
            label 'bla bla'
            customWorkspace 'D:\\'
        }
    }

    environment {
        EMAIL = 'some_emails'
        HEADER_COLOR = 'teal'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Pull git changes') {
            steps {
                ....
                }
            }
        }     

        stage('Run tests') {
            steps {
                echo "Run tests with tag: ${TESTS_RUN_TAG}"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        always {
            robot enableCache: false, logFileName: 'log.html', outputFileName: 'output.xml', outputPath: '', reportFileName: 'report.html'
            emailext attachmentsPattern: 'log.html', subject: "${JOB_NAME} build #${BUILD_NUMBER} automation results", body: """BY_BODY""", to: "${EMAIL}" 
        }
    }
}
```

So inside my post i am send email with `HTML` body (the body omitted here) and I want to change some `HTML` color base on `${currentBuild.result}` value.
So this is what I have try:

```
if (${currentBuild.result} == "SUCCESS") {                                          
    HEADER_COLOR = 'crimson'
} else {                                   
    HEADER_COLOR = 'teal'
}
```

And in my `HTML` body I am using this way:

```
bgcolor="${HEADER_COLOR}"
```

So I try to put it inside my post stage but it failed with `WorkflowScript` and i think maybe I have some syntax error or i need to put it in other place (or both)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good at groovy scripting, so I would propose the following:

```
post {
  always {
    put something here 
  }
  failure {
    mail to: team@example.com, subject: 'The Pipeline failed :('
  }
  success {
    mail to: team@example.com, subject: 'The Pipeline succeeded :)'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not including those `if block`inside script so it should be like this

```
post {
  always {
    script {
      
      if (${currentBuild.currentResult} == "SUCCESS") {                                          
        HEADER_COLOR = 'crimson'
      } else {                                   
        HEADER_COLOR = 'teal'
      }
     
      robot enableCache: false, logFileName: 'log.html', outputFileName: 'output.xml', outputPath: '', reportFileName: 'report.html'
      emailext attachmentsPattern: 'log.html', subject: "${JOB_NAME} build #${BUILD_NUMBER} automation results", body: """BY_BODY""", to: "${EMAIL}" 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 16:08:42  WorkflowScript: 64: Multiple occurrences of the post section @ line 64, column 5.
16:08:42         post {
16:08:42         ^

Comment: Line 64 it the line that stars with post {

Comment: @user1860934 please check and correct the closing ```{}```